# Сложить целые числа

Tags: java, android

Крашится при взаимодейстии именно с вот этим кодом. Все компоненты объявлены и присутствуют на XML-разметке. Спасибо.

```
tv1.setText(Integer.parseInt(tv1.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Ничего не пишет. Просто вылетает и всё.

Comment: `int a,b;`
`a = Integer.parseInt(tvBalance.getText().toString());`
`b = Integer.parseInt(etBet.getText().toString());`
`tvBalance.setText(Integer.toString(a+b+b));`

Теперь просто не суммирует.

Comment: Сработало с "Integer.toString(a+b+b)". Спасибо.